# Places api error code 7 when performing suggested search on iOS

Tags: ios, here-api

Just using Here Maps for the first time, the premium version. I tried to implement a NMASuggestionRequest but I receive:

```
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (placesapi error 7.)"
```

Is there any documentation for error codes for iOS? This error description is not very descriptive...I have been looking through the docs and googling but can not find anything that indicates what the problem could be.

edit:
I was able to get search to work, turns out the current position had not updated yet. My question still stands though, is there any error info available for generic errors like this one?

Also FYI Here team there is a typo in your docs:

[image]

The returned result is an array of NMAAutoSuggestPlace or NMAPlace (I assume, I only tried the auto suggest so far). This is in the "Text AutoSuggestion Requests" section of this page:
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics/places.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of search-related errors can be found here: [NMARequestError API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/group--nma--common.html#topic-apiref__nmarequesterror). In this case it maps to `NMARequestErrorInvalidParameter`, which is still fairly confusing for the failure you are seeing but it seems you have figured it out that a location is missing from the request.

You should be able to use `NMAPlaces::createAutoSuggestionRequestWithLocation` API with a valid `NMAGeoCoordinates` to set explicit location. Alternatively, you can set a GeoBoundingBox using the `NMARequest::viewport` property. This is mentioned in the API documentation for those methods: [NMAPlaces API Reference](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/interfacenmaplaces.html#topic-apiref__createautosuggestionrequestwithlocation-colon-partialterm-colon), "A search location context must be provided by...".

Thank you for the documentation feedback, we will update it!

Comment: oh thank you! I searched the error description on the api page and did not find that page.